ClosedXML - Using the Unique formula
I am using the unique formula with ClosedXML
All the formulas seem to work fine.  When I use the follow

ws.Cell(2,1).FormulaA1 = "=UNIQUE(MyDefinedData)";

In excel, it appears as =@UNIQUE(MyDefinedData)
